# compact sets in $\ell_{\infty}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $\ell_{\infty}$ be the usual space of bounded (reals) sequences, with the supremum norm, and $K\subset \ell_{\infty}$ compact. It is holds that $\lim_{n}x_{n}=0$ for each $(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in K$?

In $c_{0}$, if $K\subset c_{0}$ is compact, we can prove using the Arzelá-Ascoli theorem that given any $\varepsilon>0$ the is $N$ such that $|x_{n}|\leq \varepsilon$ for each $n\geq N$.

Many thanks for your comments!

Comment: Clearly no, because compact subsets are translation-invariant. If you call $e$ the sequence $e_n\equiv 1$ and $K$ is compact, then $e+K$ must be compact. And $e+K$ and $K$ cannot be both subsets of $c_0$.

Comment: Or even, trivially, singletons are always compact.

Comment: Yeah!!! Thanks.

Comment: Can you show me some interesting (nontrivial) property of compact subsets of $\ell_{\infty}$, please?